# Find convergence of $\sum_{1}^{\infty }(\ln\frac{1}{n^{\alpha }} - \ln(\sin\frac{1}{n^{\alpha }}))$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

What test do I use to find out if the series is convergent or divergent? Thanks a lot!

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\left(\ln\frac{1}{n^{\alpha }} - \ln \left(\sin\frac{1}{n^{\alpha }}\right)\right)$$

Comment: It will certainly diverge if $\alpha =0$

Comment: This is already your third question in a row in this vein. What have you tried?

Comment: OP, please show any attempt you have made.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, write this as:
$$-\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\ln\left(n^{\alpha}\sin\left(\frac{1}{n^{\alpha}}\right)\right).$$
Then, you must know that:
$$\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1 -\frac{x^2}{6} + o(x^3).$$
And that:
$$\ln(1-X) = -X - \frac{X^2}{2} + o(X^2).$$
Now, if $\alpha>0$, $\frac{1}{n^{\alpha}}\xrightarrow[n \to +\infty]{}0$. Therefore, you get: $$\ln\left(n^{\alpha}\sin\left(\frac{1}{n^{\alpha}}\right)\right) = \ln\left(1 - \frac{1}{6n^{2\alpha}} + o\left(\frac{1}{n^{3\alpha}}\right) \right) = - \frac{1}{6n^{2\alpha}} + o \left(\frac{1}{n^{3\alpha}}\right).$$
Hence, if $\alpha > \frac{1}{2}$, then the sum converges. If $\alpha \leq\frac{1}{2}$, then the sum diverges.

Answer (score 5):

$\ln(\frac 1{n^a}) - \ln(\sin\frac 1{n^a}) = \ln(\frac {\frac 1{n^a}}{\sin(\frac 1{n^a})})$

$\frac {\frac 1{n^a}}{\sin(\frac 1{n^a})} = \frac 1{1-\frac {1}{6n^{2a}} + o(n^{-4a})} =  1 + \frac 1{6n^{2a}} + o(n^{-4a})$

$\ln(1 + \frac 1{6n^{2a}}+o(n^{-4a}) = \frac 1{6n^{2a}} + o(n^{-4a})$

$\sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty \frac 1{6n^{2a}}$ converges if $2a>1$